# When typing the URL to my website, it adds words to the end

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem which I tried Googling for solutions but couldn't find it. When I type a URL of my website's page or visit it from a bookmark, it adds words at the end of the URL, leading to a 404 error.

So I have this URL:

https://www.mywebsite.com/whmcs/admin/

When I type the URL or visit it from a bookmark, it returns this:

https://www.mywebsite.com/whmcs/admin/whmcs/admin/

This is a WordPress website. What could be the problem? Thanks in advance.

```
# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteBase / 
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}$1 
</IfModule> 
# END WordPress
```

Comment: looks like a url rewrite rule that uses the wrong rewrite base perhaps

Comment: Post your .htaccess file.

Comment: `# BEGIN WordPress  
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}$1 [R=301,L]  
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}$1  
</IfModule>  
  
# END WordPress`

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Stack Overflow. How do I add a line break to code? I tried the two spaces at the end of the line and it doesn't work.

Comment: is there another `.htaccess` within the admin directory or is this it?

Comment: There no other .htaccess except for one in a directory which is a PHP script and is not related to WordPress. Could it be the culprit?

Comment: it's unlikely that this other `.htaccess` file is to blame then. I don't know anything about wordpress but if the htaccess file is not blame and this is the default htaccess file then it must be some setting with some config file but I can't guide you - sorry.

Comment: I think I have a clue. When I use http:// instead of https:// it sometimes give the error I mentioned. So could it be the SSL that has the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There should be a line-break between `RewriteEngine` and `RewriteBase`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. This error happens whether I add a slash at the end or not.